# Codrops - Jmpress.js responsive feature // Identifying function and method

Tags: jquery, css

First of all, the docs:

Plugin's site: http://jmpressjs.github.io/jmpress.js/

Codrops article: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/05/slideshow-with-jmpress-js/

Codrops demo: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlideshowJmpress/

Now, I will please ask you to resize your browser's size (width only) so that you can appreciate how the slider's content "adapts" in a very proportional and responsive way.

Question: I'd love to know how is this achieved (and, BTW, if I can integrate it easily to Pixedelic's [Camera](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/) Plugin... this would be just a plus)

Guys look, sorry if the cuestion is to "rare". I'm extremely front-end but I'm trying to get along with jQuery, and probably AngularJS in some future... Anyways, that explains the question.

Please, I know that the other way to get along with this is using @media queries but I find it really usefull and interesting the way Jmpress.js handles it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It takes a slide's content, contains it in a div and applies webkit transforms to the whole slide. Are you trying to re-develop this solution or implement jmpress in your wordpress site? Or is your question just a matter of curiosity for theory and learning?

Comment: Oh great! So it's not a jQuery solution, it simply uses CSS3 transforms. So just to know... as a matter of fact, the solution is not very backwards compatible right? The question is for curiosity and learning, as you say, but I'd also like to implement this transformations on a jQuery plugin called Camera. I don't actually know what triggers the transformations on resize... I need to understand that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, as RedGlobe pointed out, are simple CSS3 transforms.

These are applied to the full container and everything simply scales percentually.

I'll leave the CSS code to scale elements:

```
.box_scale {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
     -moz-transform: scale(0.8);  /* Firefox 3.5+ */
      -ms-transform: scale(0.8);  /* IE 9 */
       -o-transform: scale(0.8);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
          transform: scale(0.8);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}
```

For IE8 support you can use Matrix Transforms. ( more here: http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/matrices/ )

Sorry for the dumb question, but it's a great method and I didn't know it. Hope it helps someone else